# No intellisense in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've got no intellisense at all in my VS2010 installation.

I've look at the answers on here, the relevant boxes in Tools->Options are selected and I've tried the "Ctrl-alt-space" shortcut that is also mentioned but nothing.

It's not even showing "Go to definition" when I right click on a variable or auto-tabbing new lines to the right place.

Any hints?

I've tried repairing my installation - I'm not sure if my attempts to install it on my second drive (which I then abandoned) have resulted in some issues but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever installed then uninstalled/disabled resharper or any similar tool (refactor pro, etc)?

Comment: No, fresh install on a brand new PC!

I've installed VS2010 SP1, XNA and the Windows Phone SDK (no prizes for guessing what I'm doing!)

Comment: I'm also getting when I start VS... The "Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrpPackage.BootstrapPackage, Microfosft.DAta.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=nautral, PublicKeyToken=..." package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or the installation of another extension. You can get more information by running this application with the /log parameter on the command line and then examing the file "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml".

Comment: Ok, if I go Run-> devenv /resetuserdata

I can load up VS and intellisense will work.

Hurrah, fixed... until you close VS and reload it.

Comment: Ok the log file it tells me to produce above has one warning in it:

The CTM file is out of date and should be deleted and rebuilt, but the file 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033\devenv.CTM' could not be deleted.

There is no devenv.ctm (as far as I can see) in that folder - just a ResoruceCache.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, if anyone finds this later I had to use:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall

To uninstall and then reinstall VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

Tools->Import and Export Settings-> select "Reset all Settings"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem in vs2008. All of my settings were correct in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All languages -> Statement Completion as well.

After much searching, I decided to try to **close out of every open source file, close the solution and re-open it. Then re-open the affected source file.** This fixed the issue for me and intellisense/Go To Definition returned to full functionality. Unfortunately I can't back this up with hard science/any logic whatsoever, but it did the trick for me. Sorry for the anecdotal answer but thought I would share.

This article may also help: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks1ka3t6(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks1ka3t6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)